# how to get the sum of the values of two array inside an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the sample array and I really can't solved it on my own.

I want to add the values of two different array but I really don't know how

[image]

> Is that possible to add those two values of array??

Here is my sample code that I have used `array_sum()` but I end up getting only the values(not the sum of the values)

```
foreach ($_GET['Reservation'] as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {

        foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {


            echo array_sum($value2);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your `foreach` loop you can simply use `+` operator, as you don't need `array_sum` over here. `array_sum` is used for summation of `array` and not `strings`. So your simplified code is as follows

```
$arr = ['Reservation' => [3=>[56 => [2],57 => [2]],5=>[43 => [1]]]];
$res = '';
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr['Reservation'] as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $v)
        $res[$key] += $v[0];
}
print_r($res);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [3] => 4
    [5] => 1
)
```

Comment: thank you sir but it didnt work well in my case,.here is the 2nd example of my array 
'Reservation' => array ( 3 => array ( 56 => array ( 0 => '2', ), 57 => array ( 0 => '2', ), ), 5 => array ( 43 => array ( 0 => '1', ), ), ) and the result is 4 then 5,..the expected answer should be 4 then 1

Comment: here is the explanation of my array sir:
'Reservation' => array ( 3 => array ( 56 => array ( 0 => '2', ), 57 => array ( 0 => '2', ), ), 5 => array ( 43 => array ( 0 => '1', ), ), )
The number 3 is my RoomTypeID and the 56 and 57 is the RoomNo. of the RoomTypeID(the number 3) and the 2 and 2 values are the number of guest. so foreach RoomTypeID it can have many RoomNo. and in every RoomNo. has number of guest and what i want is the total of the number of guest foreach RoomTypeID

Comment: Updated answer have a look

Comment: thanks a lot sir it works now :D although i have some errors like this Notice: Undefined Offset i think i can just ignore those, thanks again sir i can now proceed to another page of my thesis :D

Comment: but i can now insert those values in my database and works correctly so i think i could just ignore those notices since it wont be seen by the user,.should I still need to solve those notices sir?